# Tomcat Http request thread count

Tags: tomcat, httprequest, tomcat8, apache-tomee

I am running Tomee 7.1.0 which has tomcat 8.x.x. As per tomcat documentation, default Http maxthreadcount 200 and acceptCount 100. my understanding is Tomcat will receive max 300 request. 200 request will be processed and 100 will be in queue and above 300 will be get connection timeout as per their documentation.

I wrote a simple Rest service and hold the request inside the rest method using Thread.sleep for 5 minutes.

started tomcat and using JConsole, I am monitoring the thread count ( Catalina -> Thread pool -> http-nio-8080- Attributes ) CurrentThreadsBusy is 0 and Connection count is 1. if send a 450 request, CurrentThreadsBusy is 200 which is correct as per their documentation, But ConnectionCount is 450 and my REst client supposed to get CONNECTION TIMEOUT, but I didn't get it why ?

> Each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that
>   request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be
>   handled by the currently available request processing threads,
>   additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the
>   value of the maxThreads attribute). If still more simultaneous
>   requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket
>   created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of
>   the acceptCount attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will
>   receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to
>   process them.

Why my client didn't get CONNECTION TIMEOUT exception after 300 request ?

How Remaining ( 150 ) request are pending in Queue ?